# convergent or divergent of infinite geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find whether the series
>
> $$\frac{1}{5^{-1}}+\frac{4}{5^0}+\frac{4^2}{5}+\frac{4^3}{5^2}+\frac{4^4}{5^3}+\cdots \cdots $$
>
> Is convergent or divergent

My trial

Let $\displaystyle \frac{1}{5^{-1}}+\frac{4}{5^0}+\frac{4^2}{5}+\frac{4^3}{5^2}+\frac{4^4}{5^3}+\cdots \cdots $

It is a infinite geometric series whose first term is $\displaystyle 5$ and common ratio $\displaystyle \frac{4}{5}$

So sum is $\displaystyle \frac{5}{1-\frac{4}{5}}=25$

But from series it goes to infinity

Whats wrong with my way. Please enlight me

How do i justified it as sum goes to infinity

Comment: "But from series it goes to infinity". What?

Comment: If you want, the series can be written as $$\frac15\left(1+\frac45+\frac{4^2}{5^2}+\frac{4^3}{5^3}+\cdots\right).$$

Comment: Yes but my question is why answer is $25$ using geo.etric series formula.

Comment: you applied the formula correctly

Comment: @Bumblebee:  did you mean $\dfrac1{5^{-1}}$?

Comment: But from series why sum goes to infinity J.W.Tanner

Comment: You have correctly identified the series as convergent, and correctly computed its sum. So, what is your question?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Yes. Thank you for correcting me. It's too late for an edit.

Comment: My question is each term is $>1$ . So for infinite terms its sum goes to infinity.

Comment: @jacky, use a calculator and compute the 20th term, it's less than 1.

Comment: @jacky: No, it is not. Consider the inequality $$\dfrac{4^{n+1}}{5^n}\ge 1.$$ It has only finitely many solutions. If you would like to compute the number of solutions, cross multiply the inequality, and then take the log and solve for $n$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
 $S=\dfrac{1}{5^{-1}}+\dfrac{4}{5^0}+\dfrac{4^2}{5}+\dfrac{4^3}{5^2}+\dfrac{4^4}{5^3}+\cdots \cdots $.

Then $\dfrac45S=4+\dfrac{4^2}{5}+\dfrac{4^3}{5^2}+\dfrac{4^4}{5^3}+\cdots.$

So $S-\dfrac45S=\dfrac1{5^{-1}}=5,$ so $\dfrac S5=5$, so $S=25$.

Comment: you could also consider the infinite series as a limit of partial sums

Answer (score 1):

Its convergent.
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^{n-1}}{5^{n-2}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\frac1{4}4^{n}}{\frac1{25}5^{n}}= \frac{25}{4} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac4{5})^{n}=\frac{25}{4}\frac{\frac4{5}}{1-\frac4{5}}=\frac{5}{1-\frac4{5}}$

Comment: What.... the geometric series has ratio 0.8<1

Comment: You see what I mean

Comment: If |r| < 1 then the geometric series converges. Refer to Achilles and the tortoise for further justification.